# Elasticsearch SHA-1 not available

Tags: java, exception, elasticsearch

I get the following error on start of elasticsearch:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: internal error: SHA-1 not available.
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.init(SecureRandom.java:108)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:79)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:197)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:161)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE.<clinit>(SunJCE.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:221)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:187)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:232)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList$3.get(ProviderList.java:147)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList$3.get(ProviderList.java:142)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getPrngAlgorithm(SecureRandom.java:553)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:193)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:161)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.SecureRandomHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandomHolder.java:26)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.MacAddressProvider.constructDummyMulticastAddress(MacAddressProvider.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.MacAddressProvider.getSecureMungedAddress(MacAddressProvider.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.TimeBasedUUIDGenerator.<clinit>(TimeBasedUUIDGenerator.java:38)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.Strings.<clinit>(Strings.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.replacePropertyPlaceholders(Settings.java:1176)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.initializeSettings(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:131)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:80)
    <<<truncated>>>
```

So I tried simple, which isn't dropping an exception:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    }
}
```

Is that an error which maybe not related to sha-1 ?

Comment: Which version of Java and ES do you have?

Comment: I run ES 2.2, but currently I saw that java version maybe is not high enough, because it doesn't fit ES requirements. It will be upgraded from my host so I can check, will update if know something new.

Comment: Yes, ES 2.2 requires at least Java 7 (no earlier than u55) or Java 8 if possible